# How To Find Excel data using Python?

Tags: python, excel

Hello to the whole community,

A few weeks ago I started learning python through Spyder, so I don't have much knowledge in this area, so I come to you for help.

I need to create code that allows through a word, I mean, when writing the word the console returns the entire line where the word is on Excel sheet. As shown in the image, the goal is to look for the employee name (Ex: Employee 1) and the console returns the salary and function.

I've tried it in a number of ways but there are always errors to occur that I can't solve.
[image: the input]

Hope you can help me and thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the path to your excel file is "file.xslx" and the sheet "mysheetname", you can use pandas:

```py
def find(df):
    name = input().strip()
    print(df[df["Employee name"] == name])

df = pd.read_excel("file.xslx", sheet_name='mysheetname')
find(df)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also explore xlrd
https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was very useful !